# javascript regex to indicate unwanted digit at the start of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript regex pattern for a string with exactly ten digits.

```
reg =/^\d{10,10}$/;
```

But I am not sure how to modify this so that it will only match string that DOES NOT start with number 1

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
^[02-9]\d{9}$
```

and you can visualize it on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%5B02-9%5D%5Cd%7B9%7D%24&str=0563412972).